# Normalize a matrix to have a specific trace value

Tags: matlab, matrix, normalization

I have a specific matrix `X`. Its trace is equal to **n**, that is, `trace(X) = n`.
A simple normalization of the columns of `X` to a length of 1 can be easily done in matlab using the function `normc`:

```
New_X = normc(X)
```

A simple normalization of the rows of `X` to a length of 1 can be easily done in matlab using the function `normr`:

```
New_X = normr(X)
```

What I am interested to do is to normalize the matrix `X` to have a trace equal to **d** not **n**. How can I achieve that? Any help will be very appreciated!!

Comment: Wouldn't `d*X/trace(X)` give you the desired matrix ? Also trace and length are different things, trace is the sum, whereas length is square root of squared sum. If you want the length of diagonal to be 1 it may be little more work.

Comment: If you want the euclidean length of diagonal to be 1 you can do `sqrt(d)*X/norm(diag(X))` and the resulting matrix will have a diagonal with length d.

Comment: @randomGuy I think you should add those as an answer. The solution is either what you said, or otherwise the problem is ill-defined (by which I mean that if an independent scaling is allowed for rows/columns, then the problem is very strongly underdetermined.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`trace` and length are different things, trace is the sum whereas length is the Euclidean length which is defined as the square root of squared sum. If you are looking to tranform the matrix such that the trace is `d` you can scale the matrix as:

```
Xtfm = d*X/trace(X)
```

If you are looking to normalize such that the Euclidean length of the diagonal is 1, you can use the following:

```
Xtfm = d*X/norm(diag(X))
```